# How can i use my scrollview on relative layout? Sliding isn't work

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

There are two circular progress bars on my activity. One of it will be below of one circular progress bar. Naturally, they doesn't fit in single Activity page and i don't want to fit them actually. What i want to do is providing that situation. I think i am in close situation but i couldn't make it.

[The position im in is this and the screen is like i want to make.It's not problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIaa2.png)

The XML code is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2000dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp"
                android:fillViewport="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">



    <com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_color="#FFCDD2"
        app:cpb_background_progressbar_width="5dp"
        app:cpb_progressbar_color="#F44336"
        app:cpb_progressbar_width="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/CircularProgressBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Jogging"
                android:id="@+id/textViewJogging"
                android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="15"
                android:id="@+id/textViewJoggingLevel"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewJogging"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="1500/2000"
                android:id="@+id/textViewProcess"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CircularProgressBar2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="%75"
                android:id="@+id/textViewPercentage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewJoggingLevel"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


        <com.mikhaellopez.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cpb_background_progressbar_color="#FFCDD2"
            app:cpb_background_progressbar_width="5dp"
            app:cpb_progressbar_color="#F44336"
            app:cpb_progressbar_width="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/CircularProgressBar2"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="%75"
            android:id="@+id/textViewPercentage2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CircularProgressBar2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="%75"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CircularProgressBar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="760dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The result is the same on my phone when i launch it but i can't slide the screen down. Sliding doesn't work. I tried everything. Can you help me? Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Change layout_height on scrollview to "match_parent" instead of 1000dp:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
```